# Interpreting the meaning of "additonal considerations" in Covid-19 reopening guidelines for cosmetology business

Tags: business, covid-19, public-health

My wife and I are trying to interpret the document

> Reopening Protocol for Personal Care Establishments:
> Appendix R Effective as of June 19, 2020t the document from LA County
> Department of Public Health,

The confusion is in a section titled:  "ADDITIONAL CONSIDERATIONS FOR NAIL SALONS"
The confusion is wether the word considerations implies "optional".

Also, the first line in "Addtional Considerations" list:

> - A plastic partition between worker and client with ample space cut out where hands or feet can be slid
>   underneath to conduct the manicure or pedicure has been provided, when feasible.

Does that mean we determine what is feasible, or does the Dept. or Health?

This is a bit confusiong for someone with limited English.

Answer (score 2):

> in a section titled: "ADDITIONAL CONSIDERATIONS FOR NAIL SALONS" The confusion is wether the word considerations implies "optional".

No. *Additional* does not mean *optional*. In fact, page 1 of [Appendix R](http://publichealth.lacounty.gov/media/Coronavirus/docs/protocols/Reopening_PersonalCare.pdf) states in bold: "*All businesses covered by this protocol must implement **all applicable** measures listed below*" (emphasis added).

Listing measures specific for nail salons in a separate section is a straight-forward way to indicate that businesses which are not --or do not involve-- nail salons don't need to be concerned about implementing those measures.

> Does that mean we determine what is feasible, or does the Dept. or Health?

You determine what is feasible, but at all times you need to "*be prepared to explain why any measure that is not implemented is not applicable to the business*". See continuation of the aforementioned statement.

Thus, if you determine that providing the "plastic partition [etc.]" is impractical or not functional, your assessment needs to be persuasive for an inspector to rule out a finding of non-compliance.